# QCameraImageCapture saves to file instead of buffer

Tags: c++, qt, qtmultimedia

I would like to when I capture a photo with my camera it doesn't create a file in the default directory but it uses the buffer instead.

So I have set the capture destination to buffer :`cameraImageCapture->setCaptureDestination(QCameraImageCapture::CaptureToBuffer)`

However it still saves a file in the directory. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. Do you have any ideas to solve my problem ? Thank you.

Comment: Did you confirm support with isCaptureDestinationSupported(...)?

Comment: Yes I did. It says true for buffer.

Comment: How do you trigger the capture? You should be listening to the QCameraImageCapture::imageAvailable() signal.
You'll  get a QVideoFrame which you can convert it to a QImage.

Comment: I do it with QImageCapture::imageCaptured(). I've just tried with imageAvailable() but it still creates an image file in my default directory.

Comment: did you sort this out? Can you post the code to handle the imageAvailable event?